# Make readwrite variables from an API class which variables are readonly

Tags: objective-c, encapsulation, readonly, getter-setter, read-write

I'm trying to *readwrite* variables from an API class which variables are *readonly*

Is it possible to get their setters from those readonly variables?

Please note that I have no access to this classes since there are from a private API.

Here is one example:

### Private APIAxes.h

```
@interface APIAxes

@property (nonatomic, readonly) double x;

@property (nonatomic, readonly) double y;

@property (nonatomic, readonly) double z; 

@end
```

### My AxesClass.m

```
@property (nonatomic) APIAxes *apiA;
- (void)updateAxes
{
    APIAxes *temp = [APIAxes alloc];
    temp.x = 0.1;  //Error x variable is readonly
    temp.y = 0.2;  //Error y variable is readonly
    temp.z = 0.3;  //Error z variable is readonly

    self.apiA = temp; // This works
}
```

Comment: If you have no access to the implementation of the class , it's not possible. Isn't there a convenience initializer to create `APIAxes` with the vectors? By the way you have to alloc **and init** the class `[[APIAxes alloc] init];`

Comment: Josh's answer is correct, though I think there needs to be an even bigger disclaimer; doing this is _almost certainly wrong_. There's a reason those properties are `readonly`, and changing the values can break a lot of internal API assumptions; the result can be wrong, and even dangerously so. If there's no initializer available to you for creating your own `APIAxes` values, I'm guessing that `APIAxes` values are either vended out by the API (in which case you're misusing the type and should create your own), or are passed in (in which case you shouldn't supply arbitrary data).

Comment: My question I guess is, can you clarify why you think you need to do this? There might be a better way to approach the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there's no initializer for this `APIAxes` class, and no setters, then it sounds like you really shouldn't try to do this. Granted that the class appears to be a pseudo-struct, a simple data object that can be put into NS collections, but absent a guarantee that an `APIAxes` instance won't change once it's been handed out to you, you stand a good chance of causing mysterious library-internal problems by monkeying with the values. If the library authors had accounted for this, they would have provided setters, or at the very least a constructor.

Now, having given the foot-shooting warning... You should be able to use Key-Value Coding to modify these values. I say "should" because, as Itai Ferber notes below, it relies on a particular naming convention, and it's possible to implement a class so that KVC won't work. But declared properties were implemented with KVC in mind, so if these are standard properties, you're all set.

KVC can change a property value even absent a setter: it will find the ivar itself if necessary via the ObjC runtime library. The only thing to note is that since these properties are primitives, you need to box the new values into `NSNumber`s first.

So `[temp setValue:@(0.1) forKey:@"x"];` should do the trick.

Comment: This is, of course, keeping in mind that if the class is not KVC compliant, you're pretty much SOL. If the class has custom ivars (e.g. the ivar for `x` is not named `x` or `_x`, even if `@synthesize`'d), KVC will throw an exception on the `-setValue:forKey:`. This is pretty rare in this day and age, but possible; I guess if you're looking to write a class that is really averse to this kind of subversion...

Comment: Yeah, I should make that explicit, @ItaiFerber, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah because `APIAxes` defined the properties as readonly, your hands are tied.  Generally what they'll give you is an initializer method that takes arguments that set those properties, but that doesn't appear to be the case?